# Why does my regular expression pattern in C# return an empty string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a a string that's formatted such `\\\State\city"`.

I want to return only the State portion and then only the city portion into respective variables.

I tried using a pattern of `^\\\\[a-zA-Z]\` to return the state portion and then a pattern of `^\\[a-zA-Z]` for the city portion.  The results are always an empty string.

```
state = Regex.Match("\\\Washington\\Seattle","^\\\\[a-zA-Z]\"].ToString();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have four backslashes? "\\\\Washington\\Seattle"?

Comment: Consider using a tool like Expresso or one of online regex validators you can find relatively easily

Comment: Use [RegEx Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/). It'll even create C# or VB.NET code for you.

Comment: First and foremost, with C#, always enclose your regex in `@"raw string"` format. (Then you'll never need to worry about the backslash soup problem again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code to match State and City...

```
var state = Regex.Match(@"\\Washington\Seattle", @"(?<=\\\\).*(?=\\)");
var city = Regex.Match(@"\\Washington\Seattle", @"(?<=\\\\.*?\\).*");
```

Comment: your pattern is perfect.  Could you describe what the pattern is doing in simple terms?  I'm trying to decipher it using the regular expression quickreference from msdn and am having a hard time.

Comment: The first pattern looks the prefix \\ and suffix \ and takes what's in between.The second pattern looks for the prefix \\(any string)\ and takes whatever is after it. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I think I got it now, (?<=\\\\).* is a grouping construct that will return anything after \\ but then you add (?=\\) which looks for \ so the .* between (?<=\\\\) and (?=\\) is the only thing that gets returned.

Answer (score 5):

Backslash serves as an escape character. For every *single* (`\`) backslash you need *two* backslashes (`\\`).

Also you do not need the beginning of line anchor `^` on your second regular expression example because that part is obviously not at the beginning of the string. Below is an example of how you could do this.

```
String s = @"\\Washington\Seattle";
Match m  = Regex.Match(s, @"(?i)^\\\\([a-z]+)\\([a-z]+)");

if (m.Success) {
   String state = m.Groups[1].Value;
   String city  = m.Groups[2].Value;

   Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", city, state); // => "Seattle, Washington"
}
```

Comment: This will work for well-formatted inputs. If the regex is also supposed to validate (unclear from the question) it could accept some invalid strings

Answer (score 2):

Try this non-RegEx answer:

```
string data = @"\\Washington\Seattle";
string state = data.Trim('\\').Split('\\')[0];
string city = data.Trim('\\').Split('\\')[1];

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", city, state);
```

This is trimming the double backslashes, then splitting at the first backslash.

Comment: Why not just replace the double backslash with an empty string to start with? Or even split on backslashes and take strings 2 and 3 instead of 0 and 1?

Comment: Really, I'd trim backslashes off the string and then split on the one in the middle. `data.Trim('\\').Split('\\');`

Comment: @JoelRondeau I like your idea better...Updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes in regex. So anywhere that you would have a single `\`, instead have `\\`

Also `[a-zA-Z]` will only match once. Use a `+` to match once or more

So that would make your state regex:

`^\\\\[a-zA-Z]+\\`

Additionally, backslashes in strings in C# *also* need to be escaped. So either double up again, or use the `@` character:

```
state = Regex.Match(@"\\Washington\Seattle",@"^\\\\[a-zA-Z]+\\").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You only allow one character to stand between your backslashes. what you actually want is `[a-zA-Z]*` with the asterisk.

Comment: Probably with a `+`. Want 1 or more, not 0 or more.